# Does the concept of stava(stotra) siddhi exist?

Tags: stotra, siddhi, stava

It is well known that a person can achieve siddhi on a mantra following the rules of sastra.

Is there such a concept of attaining siddhi on a stava?

Comment: Stava meaning Stotra?

Comment: @Rickross don't know exactly but believing that both may be different. For example: Datta Stavam

Comment: @Rickross but many of the online sources are treating stava as a form of stotra. I didn't find actual meaning.

Comment: Stava and Stotra are usually the same thing. For e.g. Lalita Stva Raja and Durga Stava Rajas both are Stotras.

Comment: @Rickross yeah true, my local language dictionary is also saying the same.